# Cloudfoundry how to let two apps sharing one database service

Tags: cloud-foundry

I bind a postgresql service for two apps. They both update the database. Problem is that I use one of the app to create the tables(database schema) by using spring jdbc namespace. But since the other one is provisioned to use a different user name and password. It can not access the tables created by another one. Anyway cloudfoundry to provide the flexibility to resolve the issue?

Comment: The two bindings should use the same user and password (which, BTW, you should not care about). Can you share a bit of your `<jdbc:xxx />` config, just to make sure you're not doing something crazy?

Comment: <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
   <jdbc:script location="classpath:/database/initdb.sql"/>
  </jdbc:initialize-database>

Comment: And I am pretty sure the username and password are different for each binding. I printed the VCAP services environment variables and they are using different username and password.

Comment: Hmmm, you're right about the username/password being different. The database name is the same though, and so my understanding is that this should be working (the intent is indeed to have apps collaborate using shared services). If you can't make this to work, I suggest opening an issue.

Answer (score 1):

For Spring apps, this can be achieved by taking the advantage of "auto-reconfigure". CF detects the bean of class javax.sql.DataSource under certain conditions and then replace the properties such as username or password with values of provisioned ones. You can find very detailed instructions here: http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/frameworks/java/spring/spring.html

Therefore for your 2 apps you can both configure the datasource connection as the same format. As long as you bind the same postgresql service to these 2 apps, although CF will inject different values to both apps, they can access same table without any explicit configurations.